# Find the extrema of $f(x)=x^{\ln(1/x)}$

Tags: calculus, optimization

I'm trying to find the extrema of the function:

$$\ f :\textstyle{\left[\frac{1}{2},4\right]} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$$
$$f(x)=x^{\ln\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)}$$

I tried to differentiate the function in order to deduce the minimum and maximum but I did not succeed. How is it possible to find them?

Answer (score 3):

Hint:$$f(x)=x^{\ln\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)}=e^{\ln\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\ln(x)}=e^{-\big(\ln(x)\big)^2}
.$$
Hence it's enough to determine the monotonicity of $g(x)=-(\ln(x))^2$, since $e^x$ is increasing on $\mathbb{R}$. This can be easily seen by a derivative test or a graph. Can you proceed from here?